# Hide the rightBarButtonItem of a navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

Does anyone know how to hide a `rightBarButtonItem` of a `UINavigationController`? In my application, I have an edit button as a `rightBarButtonItem` of a `UINavigationController`. I want to hide this ? UIBarButton` when some operations are done.

Comment: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems[1] setEnabled:NO];` if you have an array, like if you use flexible space.

Answer (score 19):

To Hide the right button: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;`

Now, to show it:

1. If you setup the right button in your view controller by assigning it to self.editButtonItem then simply assign it again in order to show it:

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
2. If you setup the right button in your view controller by allocating and initing a UIBarButtonItem, then simply keep a reference to the UIBarButtonItem in your view controller, and assign it again when you need to show it.

Comment: I tried assigning rightBarButtonItem to nil in Objective C it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

When you want it back though you will have to instanciate a button i.e.

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = 
 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                               target:self
                                               action:@selector(searchBar:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
[rightBarButton release];
```

Comment: what if i dont want to recreate object? for example, i want to hide rightBarButton to wide frame of searchBar on titleView of navigationBar.
i mean, does hiding is possible by changing property or something?

Comment: if you would like to subclass UINavigationController. you can do:         self.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;      self is your UINavigationController custom class

Answer (score 17):

If you need to hide/show the button based on some condition, try this:

```
if (condition) { 
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
} else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"my button title";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}
```

This way you don't have to save a reference to the button in a property or worry about wiring up the action on a new button.