# How to hide bar button item

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My screen flow is as follow

Login -> Registration -> CarDetails

All 3 above screens are in navigation-controller, but users are not allowed to go back from Car-Details to Registration. To achieve it, I've

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
    }
```

in CarDetails view controller. So it hides the back button which automatically gets created if controller is in navigation-controller.

So far it is good.

After providing all detail user lands on Home Screen where I've slide out menu. From menu user can goto to CarDetail Screen as well (to update). That time instead of backButton I need slide-out menu button as left bar button. So I've created it using storyboard.

The problem is that it is getting displayed after Registration view as well. I need conditional show/hide functionality for it in Car-Details View.

I've hook for it as well, as following

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if menuButtonVisibility
    {

        if self.revealViewController() != nil
        {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }

    else
    {

    }

    menuButtonVisibility=true
}
```

I only need the line to put in else block.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a bar button item for certain users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887218/how-to-hide-a-bar-button-item-for-certain-users)

Comment: What is getting displayed? "_The problem is that it is getting displayed after Registration view as well._"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can hide it by disable the button & change it tintColor like that,

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

do it right or left BarButtonItem whatever you preferred. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

you can hide it like this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

and you can add a new left button like this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped))
```

I hope that helps,

Cheers

Comment: In that situation, I'll need to remove & add bar button. I know that way I can achieve it. But am searching something better. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Try my answer for the rightBarButtonItem and see if it works with leftBarButtonItem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042818/hide-the-rightbarbuttonitem-of-a-navigation-controller/22617176#22617176

Comment: Abu Eesa Something better means?

Comment: @AbuEesa I don't know what you mean with "something better." good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.1 | Works great to hide my rightBarButton

```
  // viewDidLoad 
  self.rightBarButtonAlert.isEnabled = false
  self.rightBarButtonAlert.tintColor = .clear
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (UIBarButtonItem *item in self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems) {
        item.width = -50;
        item.enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13534705)

Comment: i checked my answer and i tested this problem , so that i post anwer.... why do you think my anser not provide to the question?

Comment: question is asking about hiding the element where your answer does not hide it just making disable. make sense?

Comment: Dont thinks your reputation more than me.. you can speak  ridiculous things

Comment: ah but uibarbtn is not hidden by set left/right navigationhidden... this is another way to hidden bar btn

Comment: if you dont try it... you can not hurry such conclusions

Comment: Make sense to me,  I will check and will comment again.

Answer (score 0):

To hide barButtonItem in swift

barbuttonItem1.isEnabled = false
barbuttonItem1.tintColor = UIColor.clear